# Understanding Prohorov's theorem

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

I've seen Prohorov's theorem in the following formulation (I'll cite only one direction). $\mathcal{M}_{\leq 1}(E)$ is the set of subprobability measures on $(E, \mathcal{B}(E))$:

> Let $(E, d)$ be a metric space and $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{M}_{\leq 1}(E)$. Then:
>
> $\mathcal{F}$ is tight $\Longrightarrow$ $\mathcal{F}$ is weakly relatively sequentially compact.

**Question 1:**

Now what does *"weakly relatively sequentially compact"* mean? Only explanation I've found: *"relatively sequentially compact regarding the weak topology"*. I don't know if I understand this. Or can somebody explain it to me?

Couldn't one just write it with weak limits?

Would the following formulation be equivalent ($\text{w-lim}$ denotes the weak limit):

> Let $(E, d)$ be a metric space and $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{M}_{\leq 1}(E)$. Then:
>
> $\mathcal{F}$ is tight $\Longrightarrow$ Every sequence $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \in \mathcal{F}$ has a subsequence $(\mu_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$, so that a $\mu\in\mathcal{M}_{\leq 1}(E)$ exists with $$\underset{k\rightarrow \infty}{\text{w-lim}}\; \mu_{n_k} = \mu \, .$$

**Question 2:**

In this formulation of the theorem *subprobability measures* were used, I think that's a bit strange, makes everything complicated and when are we really ever interested in them?

But the theorem would surely still hold if we would replace $\mathcal{M}_{\leq 1}(E)$ with $\mathcal{M}_1(E)$, which is the set of probability measures on $(E, \mathcal{B})$. Right?

Because for probability mesures $\mu_k$ we have that their weak limit must be a probability measure, too: $$\underset{k\rightarrow \infty}{\text{w-lim}}\; \mu_{k} = \mu \Longrightarrow 1 = \int 1 \, d\mu_n \overset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\longrightarrow} \int 1 \, d\mu = 1\Rightarrow \mu(E) = 1 \, .$$

Answer (score 1):

Question 1. Your formulation is indeed equivalent. Note that the " regarding the weak topology" should be replace by "topology of weak convergence of sub-probability measures" as [this corresponds rather to a weak-$*$ topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/313986/are-vague-convergence-and-weak-convergence-of-measures-both-weak-convergence).

Question 2.

> But the theorem would surely still hold if we would replace $\mathcal{M}_{\leq 1}(E)$ with $\mathcal{M}_1(E)$

This is indeed true (if you do the replacement everywhere).