# Defining weak* convergence of measures using compactly supported continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm reading some lecture notes and the author defines the following:
Let $\mu_{n},\mu$
  be probability measures on $\left(\mathbb{R}^{k},\mathcal{B}\left(\mathbb{R}^{k}\right)\right)$
 , we say $\mu_{n}$
  converge weakly to $\mu$
  if $\int fd\mu_{n}\longrightarrow\int fd\mu$
  for all continuous compactly supported functions $f:\mathbb{R}^{k}\to\mathbb{R}$
 .

An almost identical definition appears in many text books with the change of requiring the same thing for any continuous bounded function. I couldn't find any reference which showed that it actually does suffice to look only at compactly supported functions. Is this actually true?

Comment: It is true. For a proof have a look in [Knillprobability](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~knill/books/KnillProbability.pdf) theorem 2.13.2. Also have a look at page 60.

Comment: I see, the trivial measure is not a probability measure, my bad.

Comment: i don't think there is a problem in your counter example. But usually one add some condition on the (usually bounded) measures $\mu_n $, for example : for every $\varepsilon >0$ there exists a compact set $K$ such that $\mu_n(K^C)<\varepsilon$ for all $n$. this avoid having "mass escaping at infinity". Then you have the equivalence between the two properties.

Comment: @drhab I see that in page 60 it is defined for compactly supported continuous functions and at page 90 for bounded continuous function, there is no mention of it being equivalent. Obviously if $\mathcal{C}_{c}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ was dense in $\mathcal{C}_{b}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ (with respect to uniform norm)  that would justify the equivalence of the definitions but I don't think that is true.

Comment: That is somehow disappointing, I guess. Sorry. I did not dive into it, but took it for granted on base of what seemed to be promised on page 60.

Comment: Since I searched for a reference for this fact and the book already given here does not really prove it, or am I mistaken?, I will add the best reference I found:
Foundations of Modern Probability, Olav Kallenberg, 1997, Lemma 4.20

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So as i said in the comment a usefull notion here is what's called "tendue" in french, i don't know the equivalent english mathematical word for that but the english translation of the common french word "tendue" could be taut, tense or tight. I don't want to use the wrong english word so let's just use *tendue* for this post.

**edit :** as said in the comments the english word for *tendue* is "tight".

A sequences $(\mu_n)$ is said to be *tendue* if for every $\varepsilon >0$ there is a compact $K$ such that $\mu_n(K^C)<\varepsilon$ for all $n$.

If your sequence $(\mu_n)$ is *tendue* then the two definitions are equivalent, this is because in that case $C_c(\mathbb R)$ is dense in $C_b(\mathbb R)$ for the $L^1(\mathbb R, \mu_n)$-norm **uniformly in $n$**. Phrased like this it might seems a little obscure but try to show it as an exercice, it's not hard. So what we want to show now is that if (using your definition) $(\mu_n)$ converges weakly to the probability measure $\mu$ then $(\mu_n) $ is *tendue*. This will prove that the two properties are equivalent.

Now suppose that $(\mu_n)$ is not *tendue*, so there exists an $\eta>0$ such that for every compact $K$ one have $\lim \sup \mu_n(K^C)>\eta$. Since $\mu$ is a probability measure for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a compact set $K$ such that $\mu(K)>1-\varepsilon$ and $\mu(K^C)<\varepsilon$. Take $\varepsilon=\eta/2$, there is a continuous compactly supported function $f$ such that $0\leq f \leq 1$ and $\int fd\mu>1-\varepsilon>1-\eta/2$. But we also have $\liminf \int f d \mu_n<1-\eta$, which is in contradiction with the fact that $\int fd\mu_{n}\longrightarrow\int fd\mu$. This is absurd so $(\mu_n)$ must be *tendue*.

But the situation is not as nice as you could think : if you only assume that $(\mu_n)$ converge to some measure (not necessarily a probability measure) then the two definition are not equivalent. The (now deleted) example of nicomezi was a good illustration : take $\mu_n=\delta_n$, according to your definition $\delta_n$ converges weakly to $0$, but with the definition using $C_b$ functions $\delta_n$ doesn't converges. However, if you suppose that $(\mu_n)$ is *tendue* and converge weakly to some measure $\mu$ (not necessarily a probability measure) then $\mu$ is a probability measure and the two definitions are equivalent. So the good notion here is the notion of *tendue* sequences.

Comment: In English, such a set of measures is called "tight".

Comment: many thanks byron !

Comment: Do we need all the measures to be regular? it seems that you used the condition.

Comment: I can be wrong but I don't think i used it.  However I used the fact that measures are monotonous and the fact that $\mathbb R^n$ is a countable union of compact sets.

Note also that this "weak" convergence is in fact linked to the weak-$*$ convergence of measures, which deal with Radon measures (sinces they're the dual of continuous compactly supported functions) and that Radon measures are regular.