# Definition of weak convergence of random measures in probability

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence, random-matrices

In the book *Anderson, Greg W., Alice Guionnet, and Ofer Zeitouni. An introduction to random matrices. (Vol. 118. Cambridge university press, 2010.)*, the following theorem is stated:

> For a Wigner matrix, the empirical measure $L_N$ converges weakly, in probability, to the semicircle distribution.
>   In greater detail, Theorem 2.1.1 asserts that for any $f \in \mathcal{C}_b(\mathbb{R})$, and any $\varepsilon > 0$,
>   $$\begin{equation}\tag{1}\lim_{N \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(|\left<L_N, f\right> - \left<\sigma, f\right>| > \varepsilon) = 0\end{equation}$$

(The definition of Wigner matrix is standard and the empirical measure is defined as $L_N = N^{-1}\sum_{j = 1}^{N} \delta_{\lambda_j}$ where $\lambda_j$ are the (random) eigenvalues of the Wigner matrix. Also, in this case, $\sigma$ is non-random and is the standard semicircle distribution.)

My question is the following:

Convergence in probability of $M$-valued random variables $L_N$ to $\sigma$ (where $M$ is a Polish space) is defined as $$\begin{equation}\tag{2}\forall \varepsilon > 0, \lim_{N \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(d_M(L_N, \sigma) > \varepsilon) = 0\end{equation}$$ where $d_M$ is the distance on $M$. So, in the aforementioned case of the Polish space of measures on $\mathbb{R}$, we should use any of the standard equivalent metrics which metrize that space.

*How do we prove that showing $(1)$ is equivalent to showing $(2)$ in this case?*

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify what you mean by $d_M$?

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out. I have edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $d$ be your favorite metric which metrizes the weak topology on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$.

Suppose (1) holds.  Let $B(\sigma, \varepsilon)$ denote the open $d$-ball centered at $\sigma$ of radius $\varepsilon$.  This ball is open in the weak topology, which means that there exist $f_1, \dots, f_n \in \mathcal{C}_b(\mathbb{R})$ and $\delta > 0$ such that for any measure $\mu$ satisfying $|\langle \mu, f_i\rangle - \langle \sigma, f_i \rangle| \le \delta$ for $i = 1, \dots, n$, we have $\mu \in B(\sigma, \varepsilon)$.   In other words, if $d(\mu, \sigma) > \epsilon$, then $|\langle \mu, f_i\rangle - \langle \sigma, f_i \rangle| > \delta$ for some $i$.  This implies
$$\mathbb{P}(d(L_N, \sigma) > \varepsilon) \le \mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n \{|\langle L_N, f_i \rangle - \langle \sigma, f_i \rangle| > \delta\}\right) 
\le \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}(|\langle L_N, f_i \rangle - \langle \sigma, f_i \rangle| > \delta) $$
by union bound.  But the right side is a sum of $n$ terms, each of which converges to $0$ as $N \to \infty$ (according to (1)), therefore the left side also converges to 0, which gives (2).

Now suppose (2) holds, and fix any $f \in \mathcal{C}_b(\mathbb{R})$.  The map $\mu \mapsto \langle \mu, f \rangle$ is continuous with respect to $d$, so by the continuous mapping theorem (whose proof is the same in any metric space), we have $\langle L_N, f \rangle \to \langle \sigma, f \rangle$ in probability, which is precisely the statement (1).

---

A commenter asked about an almost sure version.  The following holds:

> If for every $f \in C_b(\mathbb{R})$ we have  $\langle L_N, f \rangle \to \langle \sigma, f \rangle$ almost surely, then $L_n \to \sigma$ weakly almost surely.  (The converse also holds, trivially.)

Let $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ be the space of compactly supported functions with the uniform norm.  This space is separable even though $C_b(\mathbb{R})$ is not, so let $f_1, f_2, \dots$ be a countable dense subset of $C_0(\mathbb{R})$. Then we can find a null set $E$ so that $\langle L_N(\omega), f_k \rangle \to \langle \sigma(\omega), f_k \rangle$ for all $\omega \notin E$ and all $k$.  Using the triangle inequality, we can show that for such $\omega$, we actually have $\langle L_N(\omega), f \rangle \to \langle \sigma(\omega), f \rangle$ for all $f \in C_c(\mathbb{R})$.  Indeed, fix $f \in C_c(\mathbb{R})$, let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary, and choose an $f_k$ with $\|f-f_k\|_\infty < \epsilon$.  Now
$$\begin{align*}|\langle L_N(\omega), f \rangle - \langle \sigma(\omega), f \rangle| &\le |\langle L_N(\omega), f-f_k\rangle |+ |\langle L_n(\omega), f_k \rangle - \langle \sigma(\omega), f_k \rangle| + |\langle \sigma(\omega), f_k - f \rangle| \\
&\le |\langle L_n(\omega), f_k \rangle - \langle \sigma(\omega), f_k \rangle| + 2\epsilon\end{align*}$$
since $L_N(\omega), \sigma(\omega)$ are probability measures.  Taking limsup of both sides, we have
$$\limsup_{N \to \infty} |\langle L_N(\omega), f \rangle - \langle \sigma(\omega), f \rangle| \le 2 \epsilon.$$
Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, we conclude $\limsup_{N \to \infty} |\langle L_N(\omega), f \rangle - \langle \sigma(\omega), f \rangle| = 0$, which is to say $\langle L_N(\omega), f \rangle \to \langle \sigma(\omega), f \rangle$.  But $f \in C_c(\mathbb{R})$ was arbitrary as well.

But this implies that $L_N(\omega) \to \sigma(\omega)$ weakly; see [Defining weak* convergence of measures using compactly supported continuous functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1669926/defining-weak-convergence-of-measures-using-compactly-supported-continuous-func).  As this holds for all $\omega \notin E$ we are done.

Comment: This is really cool. Just to clarify if I am understanding everything correctly, the existence of the $f_i$ follows because the weak topology is formed by unions of finite intersections of sets of the form $\{\mu | \left|\int 
 fd\mu- x\right| < \varepsilon\}$ for different $x, f$?

Comment: @MrigankaBasuRoyChowdhury: Yes, exactly.

Comment: Can you upgrade this equivalence to an almost sure version?

Comment: @Focus: Yes, see edits to answer.