# Definition of the convergence in probability of a random measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, random

I'm kind of confused about the definition of convergence in probability of a random measure $\mu_{n}$ to a deterministic limiting measure $\mu$, which are probability measures on $\mathbb R$.

**Question:** Which notion of distance on the space of probability measures $\mathrm{Pr}(\mathbb R)$ should we use to have the following equivalence?

$$\mu_n \to \mu \text{ in probability } $$ if and only if  $$\forall \phi \in C_c(\mathbb R),\ \int_\mathbb R \phi d\mu_n \to  \int_\mathbb R \phi d\mu \text{ in probability } $$ where $C_c(\mathbb R)$ is the space of all compactly supported continuous functions.

I'm actually considering the empirical spectral measures if that clarifies the problem.
I suspect that we are using Wasserstein distance and that the fact that $\mathbb R$ being $\sigma$-compact comes into play with countability...

Thanks in advance.

---

I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3483387/definition-of-weak-convergence-of-random-measures-in-probability) link which basically answers the problem. The only difference is that they used $C_b(\mathbb R)$. This can be handled from the fact that $C_c(\mathbb R)$ is dense in $C_b(\mathbb R)$ in the supremum norm which can be easily shown by utilizing smooth cutoff functions.

Answer (score 1):

There are many equivalent notions. The one you state is  true but you do have to consider $C_{b}(\mathbb{R})$ . Because that is the definition of weak convergence and convergence of expectation for compatcly supported functions only guarantee vague convergence and not tightness. Another equivalent way is $P(|\phi_{\mu_{n}}(t)-\phi_{\mu}(t)|>\epsilon)\to 0$ for each $t\in \mathbb{R}$ where $\phi$ denotes the characteristic function. Similarly one can do this for [Stieltjes transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_transformation) or moment generating functions as well(i.e. if $\mu$ is determined by moments)

The point being that convergence for $C_{c}(\mathbb{R})$ is only equivalent if you apriori know that $\mu$ itself is a probability measure. Otherwise it will not be true. That is the tricky part which you should keep in mind.

What I mean is the following:-

Let $\mu_{n}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\delta_{k}$ . Then for any $f\in C_{c}(\mathbb{R})$ you have that $\int f\,d\mu_{n}=\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k)}{n}\to 0$ as $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=0$ due to $f$ being compactly supported.

This means that $\mu_{n}\to 0$ , i.e. the $0$ measure which is not a probability measure.

But, if you apriori know that $\mu$ is a Probability measure, then convergence for $C_{c}$ functions is equivalent to convergence for $C_{b}$ functions precisely due to the reason you have stated. Then convergence for $C_{c}$ functions is indeed sufficient for the sequence $\mu_{n}$ to be tight.

Comment: Nonetheless, changing $C_b$ to $C_c$ in the statement only requires the measure $\mu$ to be finite?

Comment: No. It requires $\mu$ to be apriori, a probability measure. The example I gave gives you the $0$ measure as the limit which is obviously finite. There are examples when convergence for $C_{c}$ functions will give you only a measure $\mu$ such that $\mu(\Bbb{R})$ is strictly less than $1$.  The problem is much deeper and is a consequence of Banach Alaoglu theorem. You see, the space of finite measures is the dual of $C_{b}$. Hence to talk about compactness of a sequence(on the unit sphere) in the weak* topology, you have to work with $C_{b}$ functions.

Comment: @Focus The phenomenon that is hapenning is that $\mu(\Bbb{R})$ will always be lesser than equal to $1$ and that is trivial. But it can happen that $\mu_{n}$ converges to a measure $\mu$ which is not a probability measure.  It is convergence for $C_{b}$ functions which guarantee that. Checking for $C_{c}$ function is sufficient only if you apriori know that $\mu$ is a probability measure.  The main reason is that you cannot approximate the constant functions $1$, in the $L^{\infty}$ norm by $C_{c}$ (and hence uniformly cts) functions. So you cannot say that $\mu_{n}(\Bbb{R})\to\mu(\Bbb{R})$

Comment: @Focus Another thing to note is that you have linked the convergence of empirical spectral distribution to the Wigner semicircle . That is a separate case in itself, as $\mu_{w}$ is compactly supported (in $[-2,2]$) . So there, it does make sense to talk just about $C_{c}$ functions and also, $\mu_{w}$ is something termed as "determined by moments". So you only need to check for polynonmials(due to Weirestrass approximation) and hence only checking for monomials (moments) is enough to conclude weak convergence.

Comment: I was thinking the following. Let me denote $\mu(f)=\int_\mathbb R f d\mu$. Fix $\epsilon>0$. For some $\phi \in C_b(\mathbb R)$, let $\phi_m \in C_c(\mathbb R)$ be such that $\|\phi-\phi_m\|_{\sup}\to 0$. Then $$\mathbb P(|\mu(\phi)- \mu_n(\phi)|>\epsilon)\le \mathbb P(|\mu(\phi)- \mu(\phi_m)|>\epsilon/3)+\mathbb P (|\mu(\phi_m)- \mu_n(\phi_m)|>\epsilon/3)+\mathbb P(|\mu_n(\phi_m)- \mu_n(\phi)|>\epsilon/3).  $$  Now, we can take $m$ big enough so that the first and the third term vanishes (this is where we use that $\mu$ is finite) and then take $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @Focus You are not reading my comment nor my answers. Forget about convergence in probability and consider a deterministic probability measures $\mu_{n}$ like I defined, i.e. $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\delta_{k}$. Then $\mu_{n}$ cannot converge to a probability measure $\mu$. If you are already given that $\mu_{n}(f)\to\mu(f)$ for some probability measure $\mu$ for all $C_{c}$ functions then it's fine and you can conclude convergence for $C_{b}$ and hence weak convergence.

Comment: But if you are just given that $\mu_{n}(f)\to\mu(f)$ for all $f\in C_{c}$ then you cannot conclude that $\mu$ is a probability measure. So again consider $\mu_{n}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\delta_{k}$ and $\mu=0$ , then $\mu(1)=0$ but $\mu_{n}(1)=1$ . But you do have that $\mu_{n}(f)\to\mu(f)$ for all $f\in C_{c}$. This is why weak convergence is defined that way. i.e. $\mu_{n}$ converges weakly to $\mu$ if and only if $\mu_{n}(f)\to\mu(f)$ for all $f\in C_{b}$. It is precisely the notion of weak$^*$ convergence i.e. convergence for all evaluation maps.

Comment: I totally get what you pointed out which I appreciate. Vague convergence is strictly weaker than weak convergence, and for compactly supported $\mu$, even checking for polynomials suffices. Anyway, is there a gap in my comment above?

Comment: @Focus Yes ofcourse. That's why I gave the counterexample. You take $\mu=0$ and $\mu_{n}=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\delta_{k}}{n}$. Then they are deterministic sequences. (i.e. you can consider for each $\omega\in\Omega$ that $\mu_{n}(\omega)=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\delta_{k}}{n}$ and $\mu_{\omega}=0$. Then how in the world can you have convergence in probability or just weak convergence in this case?. The limiting measure is not a p.m. $\mu_{n}(1)=1$ and $\mu(1)=0$. So how can this be convergent?. That's why the definition is for $C_{b}$ functions.

Comment: weak convergence is nothing but weak$^{*}$ convergence for probability measures when considered as elements of the dual of the Banach space $C_{b}$. That's why you have to consider $C_{b}$ functions. I specifically mean that $P(|\mu_{n}(1)-\mu(1)|>\epsilon)=1$ for all $\epsilon<1$ in your comment. @Focus