# Convergence of Radon measures in the sense of distributions implies weak convergence

Tags: measure-theory, distribution-theory

Suppose $\mu_n, \mu$ are Radon measures such that $\mu_n \to \mu$ in the sense of distributions.  Does it follow that $\mu_n \to \mu$ in the sense of weak convergence?  What about vague convergence?

The converse, that weak convergence implies convergence in the sense of distributions, follows directly from the definition, since for distributions our class of test functions is smaller--it only contains smooth compactly supported functions.

Comment: Given how much [confusion and inconsistency](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/313986/are-vague-convergence-and-weak-convergence-of-measures-both-weak-convergence) is around these terms, it'd be better to define weak and vague convergence here. Also, are the Radon measures signed or positive?

Comment: Wait. If $f \in C^\infty_c(a,b)$  then for every $k$, as $n \to \infty$ : $\int_a^b e^{i n x} f(x)dx = o(n^k)$
Thus $n^k e^{in x} \to 0$ in the sense of distributions, but this is not true for $f \in C^0_c(a,b)$, thus the sequence of measures $\mu_n([a,b]) = \int_a^b n^k e^{in x}dx$  doesn't converge weakly or vaguely.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/284945/about-weak-convergence-of-probability-measure/284946#284946

Comment: I guess I'm not sure which definitions I want.  Would anything like reun's example work for positive measures?