# Different formulations of vague topology

Tags: real-analysis, probability, general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Given a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$, I have seen at least two ways to define vague topology on the space of signed finite Radon measures $M(X)$. They use the fact that $M(X)$, endowed with the total variation norm, is isomorphic to the dual of both $C_c(X, \mathbb R)$, the set of real-valued, continuous and compactly supported functions on $X$, and its closure (in the uniform metric) $C_0(X, \mathbb R)$, the set of real-valued continuous functions on $X$ that vanish at infinity.

The first isomorphism allows us to use the weak*-topology on $C_c(X, \mathbb R)^*$ to say that a sequence $\{\mu_n\} \subset M(X)$ converges vaguely to a limit $\mu \in M(X)$ iff
$$
\int_X f \, \mathrm{d}\mu_n \to \int_X f \, \mathrm{d}\mu \quad \text{for all } f \in C_c(X, \mathbb R). \tag{1}
$$

On the other hand, the second isomorphism allows us to use the weak*-topology on $C_0(X, \mathbb R)^*$ to say that a sequence $\{\mu_n\} \subset M(X)$ converges vaguely to a limit $\mu \in M(X)$ iff
$$
\int_X f \, \mathrm{d}\mu_n \to \int_X f \, \mathrm{d}\mu \quad \text{for all } f \in C_0(X, \mathbb R). \tag{2}
$$

I know **a relation** between these two formulations of vague convergence. Suppose we call the first formulation **c-vague** and the second formulation **0-vague**. Then 0-vague convergence of $\{\mu_n\}$ to $\mu$ is equivalent to c-vague convergence of $\{\mu_n\}$ to $\mu$ *and* $\{\mu_n\}$ being uniformly bounded.

I am new to functional analysis, and so, **can somebody shed more light on the relation between these two formulations**? In analysis literature, the 0-vague formulation is used, for example, in Riesz representation theorem. While in probability literature, the c-vague formulation is used.

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/313986/are-vague-convergence-and-weak-convergence-of-measures-both-weak-convergence) is probably the closest to what I am asking.

Comment: It is true that If $E$ is  Banach space and $D$ is dense in $E$, then a sequence of functionals $x^*_n\in E^*$ converges in the weak star topology to  $x^*\in E^*$ if and only if $(x_n^*)$ is bounded and $x_n^*(d)\to x^*(d)$ for all $d\in D$. In your case, $E=C_0(X)$ and $D=C_c(X)$.